# How do I open a file from inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, xdg-open

Ok, so running `gedit myfile.txt` works well. But what about opening a file from inside a bash script, using the default desktop app linked to the filetype?

I've tried below, which works great when run manually in terminal, but when I put it in a bash file, nothing happens:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open "myfile.txt"&
```

What should I do instead?

Please note that I need the file to stay open after the terminal is closed as well.

Comment: try providing the path of the file.. and are you sure it should be with quotes? Try without quotes

Comment: Are you sure the command does nothing?  I just created a script with the contents you list, and it opens `gedit` with the file listed (or opens a new tab in an existing session).  It returns immediately though, rather than blocking until the program exits.

Comment: In addition, what errors do you get when running your script from a terminal?

Comment: Yep. I use the full path to the file in my script but removed it here to clarify. No difference with or without quotes. I've tried `xtg-open` on `*.txt`, `*.html` and more - just wont work.

Comment: @abhishek: There are no cases where quotes are harmful in such situations, and plenty of cases where omitting quotes can cause problems. It's a good practice to make a habit of always quoting all strings, even when unnecessary, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing happens"? How do you envoke the bash script? Is the file executable? Does myfile.txt exist in the same directory as the script?

Comment: I envoke the script by double clicking on it and hitting "Run in terminal". Nothing seems to happen. File is executable.

Comment: in a terminal, `cd` to the folder containing your script and invoke your script via `./scriptname` - any errors in the terminal output?

Comment: Nope - that works great and `xdg-open` runs as intended, opening the file using the default editor.

Comment: can you pastebin.com your full script file so that we can have a look if something else is causing the issue?

Comment: Just to make clear - you want to have 1 script per 1 specific file or a generic one that opens any of the interested mimetypes with the set default application? If it's the former then based on how you're envoking you're using the wrong option, choose "run", there is no need for nor can you use "run in terminal" in that use case. If it's the latter then it can be done but has limited r. click on file value though can be interesting as a DnD default app launcher for ANY filetype

Comment: One generic script that I want to use to open the default editor for the intended file.

Comment: Make sure you are using `xdg-open` not `xtg-open` as stated above.

Comment: ```xdg-open "myfile.txt" &``` notice the space.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your script should work. But you might add something to it to get a little more information:

```
#!/bin/bash
T=`xdg-mime query filetype $1`
echo "opening file "  $1  " of type " $T "with " `xdg-mime query default $T`
xdg-open $1
echo "finished script"
```

when running this script (named my_open.sh) in a terminal like this:

```
my_open.sh path/to/somefile.txt
```

I get the following output:

```
opening file  path/to/somefile.txt  of type  text/plain with  gedit.desktop
finished script
```

which tells me that the path to the file is ok, the mimetype is recognized and the desktopfile which is used to open the file is ok as well. And gedit opens with the file in question.

Now when run on another file:

```
my_open.sh path/to/README
```

I get the following output:

```
opening file  path/to/README  of type  text/x-readme with
finished script
```

Note the different mimetype and the missing desktop file. 
Nevertheless, xdg-open opens the default for all text files (gedit).

So, you might want to add something like this to your script and see if you get unexpected output (which you can then add to your question...).

Comment: fine, except for the noisy `finished script` in the end. I recommend [http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/](The art of Unix Programming), the rule of silence. Btw.: Backticks are deprecated - prefer $(...) instead, which is nestable.

Comment: well, the script is meant to give additional information. The information given by 'finished script' is that you do not need `nohup` or `&`, but that `xdg-open` returns and lets you continue.

Comment: That's what the prompt is meant for.

Comment: true. just thought it would be more obvious that way. actually, the whole script is not needed, because it does not more than `xdg-open` already does, so this is not a production quality script anyway...

Answer (score 5):

Make a bash script test.sh as:

```
#!/bin/bash
gedit myfile.txt
```

Then, make the script executable as:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

Finally, run the script as:

```
./test.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I need to open GNOME's default file editor for the file as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe **gnome-open** instead of **xdg-open**

Comment: I found this solution worked best

Comment: What if the user isn't on Gnome?

Answer (score 2):

You are going in the correct direction. If you want the gui app to stay open when you close the terminal window then you just need to add a `nohup` at the start of the line.

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup xdg-open "myfile.txt"&
```

If the gui app is not opening its probably because you do not have the `DISPLAY` environment variable set in the shell you are trying to launch it from.  Try doing an echo `$DISPLAY`

Comment: xdg-open does neither require `nohup` nor `&`

Answer (score 0):

### The first part of your question

with the command `cat` you can open a file inside the terminal, if that is what you want (it's stated in the first part of your question).

to use it you can just type `cat FILENAME`.

### Other information

If you need more commands: 
[Here's](http://ss64.com/bash/) a good list of Commands.

### GNOME default editor

If you want to open the file in GNOME's default application `gedit`.

to use it, just type `gedit FILENAME`

Comment: That opens the file in the terminal, but not the default editor of GNOME

Comment: @industrial edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, open wont work either...

Comment: @Industrial What are you asking for? explain your question further! you say several different things and I have answered one of them but you say you don't want to use it...

Comment: @Industrial the default text editor in GNOME **is** gedit aka "text editor" so if you run `gedit file.filetype` you will open the file as you want!

Comment: Hi again! I appreciate your answer a lot. As mentioned in the question - I want to be able to "opening a file from inside a bash script, using the default desktop app linked to the filetype" - that's regardless of the file's being a `*.txt` or `.jpeg` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

While I' not sure what's really to be accomplished here & based on some recent comments that **a single script should open ANY file in default app** or to extent the app supports this.

**If so** then  easiest way to do that would be by opening a terminal & going scriptname /path/to/filename or if there are any spaces in path then scriptname '/path/to/filename'

```
cd; mkdir -p bin && gedit ~/bin/openit1
```

Use this as a script, you can use any name you wish for script, I'll use openit1 as example. It's best when using scripts directly from ~/bin to add a number to name so no conflicts with any existing linux commands

```
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open "$1"
```

Close out gedit & in the terminal

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/openit1
```

Restart to add ~/bin to your $PATH

To invoke open a terminal and go

```
openit1 /path/to/filename or openit1 'path/to/filename'
```

**IF as orig stated** & using the orig. script for **one particular file per script** & invoking by d. left clicking on the script you just need to choose "**Run**" instead of "Run in Terminal"

Comment: `Restart to add ~/bin to your $PATH` - uhm, old Windows habits? ;)